# openid authentication tables and what do they mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I installed the ruby on rails plugin "open_id_authentication". After running the migration it created two tables "open_id_authentication_associations" and "open_id_authentication_nonces" does anyone know what those tables do and how they are used?

Thanks

Comment: The read me file that comes with the plugin does not give any info on the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iHeartDucks,

Here is a site that has much more discussion on what exactly is happening with the [open_id_authentication](http://www.ddj.com/web-development/210603354?pgno=2) plugin, and why it needs these tables.  You will find:

These tables, "open_id_authentication_associations" and "open_id_authentication_nonces", store information about the messages received from OpenID identity providers, including authentication keys.

### Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `open_id_authentication_nonces` table stores the [`openid.response_nonce`](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#positive_assertions) value, which is basically a string starting with a timestamp and ending with a unique value.

The `open_id_authentication_associations` table stores information like the OpenID server url, username, secret, etc - the information needed for the user to authenticate.